# How can I make my tooltip not to hide in browser window

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want a tooltip wordpress plugin or jquery plugin for my Wordpress website inorder to show some description in it and I want my tooltip not to hide in any browser window.
Could anyone suggest me the best plugin.
I want the plugin some thing like this in this website 
http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip

Comment: Bootstrap has a nice tooltip

Comment: Thanks Mishra It was awesome plugin.I have been searching for this kind of plugin.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Thejdeep, you should checkout the qTip2 jQuery plugin.  It is extremely configurable, has an extensive web site, and the developer is extremely dedicated and responsive.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

There is a recent WP plugin that features qTip (http://wordpress.org/plugins/myqtip-easy-qtip2/) but it may not offere all the flexibility you get with editing your template to use the core code.

Remember when adding jQuery to WP at the theme level: enqueue your scripts, and be aware that WP loads jQuery in no conflict mode.